# Border line bottom curved top straight

Tags: html, css, border, tailwind-css, curve

I want to make a curved line between parts like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVLNE.png). Because if I now try to curve my borderline, the top also curves. I use nuxt.js and tailwind for css. I did not finish the code yet, but you can see where I want the lines. And I'm also checking how I will get the pictures in the right place.

**Code**

```
<template>
    <div class="bg-gray-100 h-auto">
        <div class="lg:mx-32 xl:mx-60 h-96 w-auto text-blue-900">
            <div class="py-20">
                <h3 class="text-4xl font-bold text-center">Nuestro proceso de Check-in</h3>
            </div>
            <h1 class="font-bold text-7xl text-gray-300 ml-10">1</h1>
            <div class="relative border-l-2 border-b-2 border-dashed rounded-xxl border-blue-900 w-1/2">
                <div class="m-10">
                    <h3 class="text-3xl font-bold items-end col-start-1 row-start-2 h-auto"><u>Escanea</u> el
                        documento<br>del viajero</h3>
                    <p class="col-start-1 row-start-3">
                        Con solo escanear el código MRZ ubicado en la parte inferior
                        del DNI o Pasaporte del viajero, nuestra app registra al
                        instante todos sus datos personales.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="relative w-1/2">
                <!-- <div class="layer0 bg-contain bg-no-repeat h-full w-2/3" :style="passport"></div>
                <div class="layer1 bg-contain bg-no-repeat h-full w-2/3" :style="phone"></div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="relative grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-5 h-96 w-auto">
                <div class="absolute border-r-2 border-dashed rounded-xxl border-blue-900 bg-contain bg-no-repeat h-full w-1/2 row-span-4"
                     :style="sign"></div>
                <div class="col-start-2 ml-5">
                    <h1 class="font-bold text-7xl text-gray-300 col-start-2 row-start-1">2</h1>
                    <h3 class="text-3xl font-bold items-end col-start-2 row-start-2 h-auto"><u>Firma</u> del huésped
                    </h3>
                    <p class="col-start-2 row-start-3">
                        Una vez escaneado su documento, completa el registro
                        con la firma digital de tu huésped, usando su
                        dedo o un puntero
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    .layer0 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .layer1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 62%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {},
        data() {
            return {
                passport: {backgroundImage: "url(passport.png)"},
                phone: {backgroundImage: "url(phone_scan.png)"},
                sign: {backgroundImage: "url(sign.png)"}
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Pls include the code here or else how will we solve your problem?

Comment: This should help you put code into your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We need to know how you are positioning things so show the HTML and the CSS - for example, are you using grid?

Answer (score -2):

You can go to [figma.com](https://www.figma.com/)

1. use the pen tool
2. create the shape/lines you want.
3. then right click the shape/lines `Copy as SVG`
4. paste it in your code.

As it is as SVG code you can apply CSS to it and use it how ever you want